# Find possible subsequence in a sequential time-series in polars dataframe

Tags: python-polars

I will try to explain this as good as possible, because I am unfortunately quiet new to polars. I have a large time series dataset where each separate timeseries is identified with a `group_id`. Additionally, there is a `time_idx` column that identifies which of the possible time series step is present and have a corresponding target value if present. As a minimal example, consider the following:

```
min_df = pl.DataFrame(
        {"grop_idx": [0, 1, 2, 3], "time_idx": [[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [0, 2, 3], [0,3]]}
    )

┌──────────┬───────────────┐
│ grop_idx ┆ time_idx      │
│ ---      ┆ ---           │
│ i64      ┆ list[i64]     │
╞══════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 0        ┆ [0, 1, 2, 3]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1        ┆ [2, 3]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2        ┆ [0, 2, 3]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3        ┆ [0, 3]        │
└──────────┴───────────────┘
```

Here, the time range in the dataset is 4 steps long, but not for all individual series all time steps are present. So while `group_idx=0` has all present steps, `group_idx=0` only has step 0 and 3, meaning that for step 1 and 2 no recorded target value is present.

Now, I would like to obtain all possible sub sequences so that we start from each possible time step for a given sequence length and maximally go to the `max_time_step` (in this case 3). For example, for `sequence_length=3`, the expected output would be:

```
result_df = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "group_idx": [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
            "time_idx": [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [0,2,3], [0,2,3], [0,3], [0,3]], 
            "sub_sequence": [[0,1,2], [1,2,3], [None, None, 2], [None, 2, 3], [0, None, 2], [None, 2, 3], [0, None, None], [None, None, 3]]
        }
    )

┌───────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ group_idx ┆ time_idx      ┆ sub_sequence    │
│ ---       ┆ ---           ┆ ---             │
│ i64       ┆ list[i64]     ┆ list[i64]       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 0         ┆ [0, 1, ... 3] ┆ [0, 1, 2]       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0         ┆ [0, 1, ... 3] ┆ [1, 2, 3]       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1         ┆ [2, 3]        ┆ [null, null, 2] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1         ┆ [2, 3]        ┆ [null, 2, 3]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2         ┆ [0, 2, 3]     ┆ [0, null, 2]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2         ┆ [0, 2, 3]     ┆ [null, 2, 3]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3         ┆ [0, 3]        ┆ [0, null, null] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3         ┆ [0, 3]        ┆ [null, null, 3] │
└───────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

All of this should be computed within `polars`, because the real dataset is much larger both in terms of the number of time series and time series length.

**Edit**:
Based on the suggestion by @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ I have tried the following on the actual dataset (~200 million rows after `.explode()`). I forgot to say that we can assume that that `group_idx`and `time_idx` are already sorted. However, this gets killed.

```
(
 min_df.lazy()
     .with_column(
         pl.col("time_idx").alias("time_idx_nulls")
     )
     .groupby_rolling(
          index_column='time_idx',
          by='group_idx',
          period=str(max_sequence_length) + 'i',
     )
     .agg(pl.col("time_idx_nulls"))
     .filter(pl.col('time_idx_nulls').arr.lengths() == max_sequence_length)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an algorithm that needs only the desired sub-sequence length as input.  It uses `groupby_rolling` to create your sub-sequences.

```py
period = 3
min_df = min_df.explode('time_idx')
(
    min_df.get_column('group_idx').unique().to_frame()
    .join(
        min_df.get_column('time_idx').unique().to_frame(),
        how='cross'
    )
    .join(
        min_df.with_column(pl.col('time_idx').alias('time_idx_nulls')),
        on=['group_idx', 'time_idx'],
        how='left',
    )
    .groupby_rolling(
        index_column='time_idx',
        by='group_idx',
        period=str(period) + 'i',
    )
    .agg(pl.col("time_idx_nulls"))
    .filter(pl.col('time_idx_nulls').arr.lengths() == period)
    .sort('group_idx')
)
```

```
shape: (8, 3)
┌───────────┬──────────┬─────────────────┐
│ group_idx ┆ time_idx ┆ time_idx_nulls  │
│ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---             │
│ i64       ┆ i64      ┆ list[i64]       │
╞═══════════╪══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 0         ┆ 2        ┆ [0, 1, 2]       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0         ┆ 3        ┆ [1, 2, 3]       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1         ┆ 2        ┆ [null, null, 2] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1         ┆ 3        ┆ [null, 2, 3]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2         ┆ 2        ┆ [0, null, 2]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2         ┆ 3        ┆ [null, 2, 3]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3         ┆ 2        ┆ [0, null, null] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3         ┆ 3        ┆ [null, null, 3] │
└───────────┴──────────┴─────────────────┘
```

And for example, with period = 2:

```
shape: (12, 3)
┌───────────┬──────────┬────────────────┐
│ group_idx ┆ time_idx ┆ time_idx_nulls │
│ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---            │
│ i64       ┆ i64      ┆ list[i64]      │
╞═══════════╪══════════╪════════════════╡
│ 0         ┆ 1        ┆ [0, 1]         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0         ┆ 2        ┆ [1, 2]         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0         ┆ 3        ┆ [2, 3]         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1         ┆ 1        ┆ [null, null]   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1         ┆ 2        ┆ [null, 2]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1         ┆ 3        ┆ [2, 3]         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2         ┆ 1        ┆ [0, null]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2         ┆ 2        ┆ [null, 2]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2         ┆ 3        ┆ [2, 3]         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3         ┆ 1        ┆ [0, null]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3         ┆ 2        ┆ [null, null]   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3         ┆ 3        ┆ [null, 3]      │
└───────────┴──────────┴────────────────┘
```

##### Edit: managing RAM requirements

One way that we can manage RAM requirements (for this, or any other algorithm on large datasets) is to find ways to divide-and-conquer.

If we look at our particular problem, each line in the input dataset leads to results that are independent of any other line.  We can use this fact to apply our algorithm in batches.

But first, let's create some data that leads to a large problem:

```py
min_time = 0
max_time = 1_000
nbr_groups = 400_000
min_df = (
    pl.DataFrame({"time_idx": [list(range(min_time, max_time, 2))]})
    .join(
        pl.arange(0, nbr_groups, eager=True).alias("group_idx").to_frame(),
        how="cross"
    )
)
min_df.explode('time_idx')
```

```
shape: (200000000, 2)
┌──────────┬───────────┐
│ time_idx ┆ group_idx │
│ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ i64      ┆ i64       │
╞══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0        ┆ 0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2        ┆ 0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4        ┆ 0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6        ┆ 0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...      ┆ ...       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 992      ┆ 399999    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 994      ┆ 399999    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 996      ┆ 399999    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 998      ┆ 399999    │
└──────────┴───────────┘
```

The input dataset when exploded is 200 million records .. so roughly the size you describe.  (Of course, using divide-and-conquer, we won't explode the full dataset.)

To divide-and-conquer this, we'll `slice` our input dataset into smaller datasets, run the algorithm on the smaller datasets, and then `concat` the results into one large dataset.  (One nice feature of `slice` is that it's very cheap - it's simply a window into the original dataset, so it consumes very little additional RAM.)

Notice the `slice_size` variable.  You'll need to experiment with this value on your particular computing platform.  You want to set this as large as your RAM requirements allow.  If set too low, your program will take too long.  If set too high, your program will crash.  (I've arbitrarily set this to 10,000 as a starting value.)

```py
time_index_df = (
    pl.arange(min_time, max_time, eager=True, dtype=pl.Int64)
    .alias("time_idx")
    .to_frame()
    .lazy()
)


period = 3
slice_size = 10_000
result = pl.concat(
    [
        (
            time_index_df
            .join(
                min_df
                .lazy()
                .slice(next_index, slice_size)
                .select("group_idx"),
                how="cross",
            )
            .join(
                min_df
                .lazy()
                .slice(next_index, slice_size)
                .explode('time_idx')
                .with_column(pl.col("time_idx").alias("time_idx_nulls")),
                on=["group_idx", "time_idx"],
                how="left",
            )
            .groupby_rolling(
                index_column='time_idx',
                by='group_idx',
                period=str(period) + 'i',
            )
            .agg(pl.col("time_idx_nulls"))
            .filter(pl.col('time_idx_nulls').arr.lengths() == period)
            .select(['group_idx', 'time_idx_nulls'])
            .collect()
        )
        for next_index in range(0, min_df.height, slice_size)
    ]
)

result.sort('group_idx')
```

```
shape: (399200000, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────────────┐
│ group_idx ┆ time_idx_nulls    │
│ ---       ┆ ---               │
│ i64       ┆ list[i64]         │
╞═══════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 0         ┆ [0, null, 2]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0         ┆ [null, 2, null]   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0         ┆ [2, null, 4]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0         ┆ [null, 4, null]   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...       ┆ ...               │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 399999    ┆ [994, null, 996]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 399999    ┆ [null, 996, null] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 399999    ┆ [996, null, 998]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 399999    ┆ [null, 998, null] │
└───────────┴───────────────────┘
```

##### Some other things

You do actually need to use the joins.  The joins are used to fill in the "holes" in your sequences with `null` values.

Also, notice that I've put each `slice`/batch into lazy mode, but **not** the entire algorithm.  Depending on your computing platform, using lazy mode for the entire algorithm may again overwhelm your system, as Polars attempts to spread the work across multiple processors which could lead to more out-of-memory situations for you.

Also note the humongous size of my output dataset: almost 400 million records.  I did this purposely as a reminder that your output dataset may be the ultimate problem.  That is, any algorithm would fail if the result dataset is larger than your RAM can hold.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately, the query gets killed for my dataset, which after explode is (~200 million rows) long. First I think it was failing on the join, but assuming that both `group_idx` and `time_idx` are already sorted, I think the first two joins can be removed and only begin with the `groupby_rolling` and also remove the sort at the end. However, this still fails calling the groupby in lazy mode. So I was wondering if you have thoughts on that?

Comment: For a given computing platform with fixed RAM, any algorithm will fail - once the problem gets large enough.  My suggestion is to first try the solution by @jqurious on your actual.  If that solution doesn't work for your data, I'll edit my answer with a fix that I know will work.

Comment: I believe the current answer by @jqurious is not giving the correct answer. Either way, I would be interested in your work around solution, if it is not too much trouble, because I am trying to better understand polars.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a method that you can use on many too-large-for-RAM algorithms.  So even if you find a better algorithm for this particular question, it's still handy to know how to do the above.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation, that helped a lot. I think only one change: when constructing the `time_index_df` the range should go from `min_time` to `max_time + 1` otherwise the last time step is forgotten, i.e with the original `min_df` and `period=3` it would not yield the correct result otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there should be a cleaner way to do this but you could create range/mask list columns:

```
>>> max_time_step = 3
>>> sequence_length = 3
>>> (
...    min_df
...    .with_columns([
...       pl.arange(0, max_time_step + 1).list().alias("range"),
...       pl.col("time_idx").arr.eval(
...          pl.arange(0, max_time_step + 1).is_in(pl.element()),
...          parallel=True
...       ).alias("mask")
...    ])
... )
shape: (4, 4)
┌───────────┬───────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ group_idx | time_idx      | range         | mask                     │
│ ---       | ---           | ---           | ---                      │
│ i64       | list[i64]     | list[i64]     | list[bool]               │
╞═══════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ 0         | [0, 1, ... 3] | [0, 1, ... 3] | [true, true, ... true]   │
├───────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ 1         | [2, 3]        | [0, 1, ... 3] | [false, false, ... true] │
├───────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ 2         | [0, 2, 3]     | [0, 1, ... 3] | [true, false, ... true]  │
├───────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ 3         | [0, 3]        | [0, 1, ... 3] | [true, false, ... true]  │
└─//────────┴─//────────────┴─//────────────┴─//───────────────────────┘
```

You can then `.explode()` those columns, replace `true` with the number and group them back together.

**Update #1:** Use @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ's `.groupby_rolling()` technique to
generate correct sub-sequences.

**Update #2:** Use regular `.groupby()` and `.list().slice()` to generate sub-sequences.

```
>>> min_df = pl.DataFrame({
...    "group_idx": [0, 1, 2, 3], 
...    "time_idx": [[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [0, 2, 3], [0,3]]
... })
... max_time_step = 3
... sequence_length = 2
... (
...    min_df
...    .with_columns([
...       pl.arange(0, max_time_step + 1).list().alias("range"),
...       pl.col("time_idx").arr.eval(
...          pl.arange(0, max_time_step + 1).is_in(pl.element()),
...          parallel=True
...       ).alias("mask")
...    ])
...    .explode(["range", "mask"])
...    .with_column(
...       pl.when(pl.col("mask"))
...         .then(pl.col("range"))
...         .alias("value"))
...    .groupby("group_idx", maintain_order=True)
...    .agg([
...        pl.col("value")
...          .list()
...          .slice(length=sequence_length, offset=n)
...          .suffix(f"{n}")
...        for n in range(0, max_time_step - (1 if max_time_step % sequence_length == 0 else 0))
...    ])
...    .melt("group_idx", value_name="subsequence")
...    .drop("variable")
...    .sort("group_idx")
... )
shape: (12, 2)
┌───────────┬──────────────┐
│ group_idx | subsequence  │
│ ---       | ---          │
│ i64       | list[i64]    │
╞═══════════╪══════════════╡
│ 0         | [0, 1]       │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 0         | [1, 2]       │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 0         | [2, 3]       │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1         | [null, null] │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1         | [null, 2]    │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│ ...       | ...          │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 2         | [null, 2]    │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 2         | [2, 3]       │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 3         | [0, null]    │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 3         | [null, null] │
├───────────┼──────────────┤
│ 3         | [null, 3]    │
└─//────────┴─//───────────┘
```

It feels like you should be able to use `pl.element()` inside `.then()` here to avoid the explode/groupby but it fails:

```
>>> (
...    min_df
...    .with_column(
...       pl.col("time_idx").arr.eval(
...          pl.when(pl.arange(0, max_time_step + 1).is_in(pl.element()))
...            .then(pl.element()),
...          parallel=True)
...       .alias("subsequence")
...    )
... )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ShapeError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I think your suggestion is limited to the minimal example, because it only extracts two subsequences in the line `pl.col("value").shift(-1).head(sequence_length).suffix("1")`. In my use case the sequence length can vary. So for example, with sequence length of 2 one should get the output that @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ shows for the case `period=2`. I am sorry if I didn't explain this well enough in my problem statement.

Comment: @nleh Indeed it is, my bad - I didn't understand the problem correctly. I've replaced that part with @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ's `.groupby_rolling()` approach. I suspect their `.join()` approach is superior than the `.arr.eval()` here though.

Comment: @nleh I've made another update - using `.list().slice()` inside `.agg()` seems to perform better than `.groupby_rolling()` in my particular testing.